# MySQL SELECT with Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select some rows from my database from multiple tables

First table:

```
 Table name: ctud
 --------------------------------
 id  +   user_id   +  dep_id  
 1          1            1
 2          2            1
 3          3            2
 4          4            3
```

Second table:

```
 Table name: cdot
 -------------------------------
 id   +    username   +   name
 1          Hello         Emre
 2          Merhaba       Emma
 3          Aloha         Micheal
 4          Yup           Test
```

I want to take data from both tables and for this, I am using this code:

```
 select * 
 FROM ctud,cdot
 where ctud.user_id = cdot.username
 and ctud.user_id = 1;
```

but I get a blank screen.. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: `ctud.user_id` is the user's id, a number, `cdot.username` is a string, the user's name. You cannot join based on this. You need to use another table that would have both `user_id` and `username` and use that table _also_ in your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join your tables on this condition

```
ctud.user_id = cdot.username
```

but `ctud.user_id` is for instance `1` and `cdot.username` `Hello`.

That does not match and won't return results. You need 2 columns in those tables that contain **the same values** to make a connection of these tables.

You probably wanted to do

```
 select * 
 FROM ctud
 join cdot on ctud.user_id = cdot.id
 where ctud.user_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need this code

```
 select * 
 FROM ctud,cdot
 where ctud.user_id = cdot.id and ctud.user_id = 1;
```